# Why is geom_roc from ggplot vs plot.roc giving such drastic difference in ROC?

Tags: r, r-caret, roc

I supposed I have a training sent here.

```
library(caret)
library(mlbench)
library(plotROC)
library(pROC)

data(Sonar)
ctrl <- trainControl(method="cv", 
                     summaryFunction=twoClassSummary, 
                     classProbs=T,
                     savePredictions = T)
rfFit <- train(Class ~ ., data=Sonar, 
               method="rf", preProc=c("center", "scale"), 
               trControl=ctrl)
    
# Select a parameter setting
selectedIndices <- rfFit$pred$mtry == 2
```

and I would like to plot the ROC.

```
plot.roc(rfFit$pred$obs[selectedIndices],
         rfFit$pred$M[selectedIndices])
```

[image]

however when I tried a ggplot2 approach it gives me something completely different.

```
g <- ggplot(rfFit$pred[selectedIndices, ], aes(m=M, d=factor(obs, levels = c("R", "M")))) + 
  geom_roc(n.cuts=0) + 
  coord_equal() +
  style_roc()

g + annotate("text", x=0.75, y=0.25, label=paste("AUC =", round((calc_auc(g))$AUC, 4)))
```

[image]

Im doing something really wrong here but I can't figure out what it is.
thanks.

Comment: You are plotting different graphs, aren't you? The first graph is for specificity and the second for FPR. Moreover you can see that the graphs are quite symmetric (flip the graph twice-horizontally and vertically and they will match

Comment: @asd-tm not really. FPR is 1-specificity, and the x axis of the base R plot is reversed, so although it is labelled Specificity it is actually showing FPR.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of your factor levels is ignored by `geom_roc`. Notice that whichever way round your assign your `levels = c('R', 'M')`, you get the warning:

```r
#> Warning message:
#> In verify_d(data$d) : D not labeled 0/1, assuming M = 0 and R = 1!
```

This means you are getting the ROC of an 'anti-prediction' (i.e. the opposite of the prediction your model actually makes). Hence it is a mirror image of the actual ROC.

You need to explicitly convert the predictions to a numeric column of 1s and 0s:

```r
g <- ggplot(rfFit$pred[selectedIndices, ], 
       aes(m=M, d= as.numeric(factor(obs, levels = c("R", "M"))) - 1)) + 
  geom_roc(n.cuts=0) + 
  coord_equal() +
  style_roc()

g + annotate("text", x=0.75, y=0.25, 
           label=paste("AUC =", round((calc_auc(g))$AUC, 4)))
```

[image]